# How to update the people and group column with multiple values in SharePoint

Tags: development, lookup-column, multiple-values, settings, person-or-group

I have a person or group column in SharePoint 2013 I want to set the multiple values I have set its value like 1;#pallavi it's working but when done for multiple values like 1;#pall;#2;#shee it's not working can anybody help me with this? 
I am using c# this is my code snipped

private WebRequest createWebRequest(string RequestType, string fileName, string htmlCode, List clients)
        {
            dynamic request = null;
            request = new DisclosureWebRequest();
            int numberOfExpiryMonths = new ReminderSPService().GetExpiryOfADocument(Constants.DISCLOSURE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            int masterDocumentIdDisclosure = ClientMasterDocumentsSharePointServices.GetMasterDocumentIdDisclosure();
            DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime expiryDate = numberOfExpiryMonths > 0 ? today.AddMonths(numberOfExpiryMonths) : today.AddMonths(12);
            var analysts = "1192;#Monica Castro;#2786;#Winnie the Pooh";
            request.MetaDataJSON = "{" + string.Format("" +
                "'{0}':'{1}', " +
                "'{2}': '{3}', " +
                "'{4}': '{5}', " +
                "'{6}': '{7}', " +
                "'{8}': '{9}', " +
                "'{10}': '{11}', " +
                "'{12}': '{13}', " +
                "'{14}':'{15}'," +
               "'{16}':'{17}'," +
                 "'{18}':'{19}'," +
                "'{20}':'{21}'"
               ,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_CLIENTDOCUMENTSTATUS, "Green",
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_DOCUMENT_PRIORITY, "Primary Source",
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_MASTERDOCUMENTID, masterDocumentIdDisclosure,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_SIGNED_DATE, today,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_PBSEXPIRES, expiryDate,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_CLIENTID, Clientid,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_ISALLPARENTSIGNED, hidIsParentSigned.Value,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_ISALLANALYSTSIGNED, hidIsAnalystSigned.Value,
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_HTML, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlCode),
            Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_ANALYSTDETAIL, hidParentAnalystDetail.Value,
              Constants.DISCLOSURE_FIELD_Analysts, analysts
            )
            + "}";

```
        request.FileName = fileName;
        //string url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        string url = "http://52.171.137.86";
        var htmlCodeForPDF = "";
        if (Convert.ToInt32(hidIsParentSigned.Value) == 1 && Convert.ToInt32(hidIsAnalystSigned.Value) == 1)
        {
            htmlCodeForPDF = hidPageHTML.Value;
            htmlCodeForPDF = htmlCodeForPDF.Replace("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"", "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" + url);
            htmlCodeForPDF = htmlCodeForPDF.Replace("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"", "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + url);
            request.HTML = htmlCodeForPDF;
        }
        else
        {
            request.HTML = "";
        }
```

here analyst is person or group column

Thanks

Comment: Please describe it more like in which version of SharePoint you are trying and which programming language you are using and please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below PowerShell command we can update the multi-value people or group column:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/pmo"
$ListName="Projects"
$FieldName= "ProjectMembers" #Internal Name
$ListItemID="25"
$UserIDs=@("salaudeen.rajack@crescent.com","Charles.jonathan@crescent.com","mark.jones@crescent.com")

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials

#Get the List & Item to update
$List = $Ctx.Web.lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItem = $List.GetItemById($ListItemID)
$Ctx.Load($ListItem)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Resolve each user ID and get the User Objects
$UserValueColl = @()
ForEach($UserID in $UserIDs)
{
    #Get the User to Update
    $SPOUser = $Ctx.Web.EnsureUser($UserID)
    $Ctx.Load($SPOUser)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    If($SPOUser -ne $Null)
    {
        $SPOUserValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
        $SPOUserValue.LookupId = $SPOUser.id
        $UserValueColl += $SPOUserValue
    }
}

IF($UserValueColl.length -gt 0)
{
    $UserValueCollCollection = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]]$UserValueColl
    #Update the Multi-People picker column
    $ListItem[$FieldName] = $UserValueCollCollection
    $ListItem.Update()
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host -f Green "List Item has been updated!"
}
```

Reference URL:

[SharePoint Online: Read / Update Person or Group Field (People Picker) Values using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/10/sharepoint-online-get-set-person-or-group-people-picker-field-using-powershell.html)

**Using C# client-side object model coding:**

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(weburl);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord); 

List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");
ListItem currentItem = list.GetItemById(1);

FieldUserValue[] userValueCollection = new FieldUserValue[1];

//Get all the users of this Web
UserCollection userCollection = this.ctx.Web.SiteUsers; 
this.ctx.Load(userCollection, w => w.Include(p => p.Id, p => p.Title));
this.ctx.ExecuteQuery(this.ctx);

User user = userCollection.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Title.ToLower().Trim() == userTitle.ToLower().Trim());

//Making sure that a user of title userTitle is present in this Web
if (user != null)
{
    FieldUserValue fieldUserVal = new FieldUserValue();
    fieldUserVal.LookupId = user.Id;
    userValueCollection.SetValue(fieldUserVal, 0);
}

currentItem["MultiUserValCol"] = userValueCollection;
currentItem.Update(); 
this.ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Source:

[Update a UserMulti Column value in Client Object Model C#](https://piyushksingh.com/2014/01/19/update-a-usermulti-column-value-in-client-object-model-c/)

**Using the REST API:**

```
var spID =_spPagecontextinfo.userid;//to add current user

strUrl = “http://<site url>//_api/web/lists/getbytitle(‘ListName’)/items”;
strheader= {“Accept”: “application/json;odata=verbose”,
“X-RequestDigest”: $(“#__REQUESTDIGEST”).val()
};

var itemType = ‘SP.Data.ListNameListItem’;///ListItemEntityTypeFullName
var item = {
“__metadata”: { “type”: itemType },
         StakeholderId:spID
};
$.ajax({
url: strUrl,
type: “POST”,
async:false,
cache:false,
contentType: “application/json;odata=verbose”,
data: JSON.stringify(item),
headers:strHeader,
success: function (data){
///your code on success
},
error: function (error) {
//return alert(error.responseText);
}
});
```

Source:

[Updating Person/Group column using Jquery REST API and Client Object model](https://sharepointcrib.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/updating-sharepoint-person-or-group-column-using-jquery-rest-api-and-client-object-model/)

Using the Microsoft flow, refer to the below article:

[Updating a multi-people field in SharePoint with Microsoft Flow](https://www.about365.nl/2018/08/06/updating-a-multi-people-field-in-sharepoint-with-microsoft-flow/)